# Facebook - how should look like the correct LIKE button with posting to timeline/wall?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am fighting the whole days with this thing, I would like to add to my website the like button to each article and when a visitor click on the LIKE button, then on his/her timeline/wall should be shown this information.

Could anyone help me with this? The like button itself is working, but I don't know how to put this information to the timeline.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

By default when a user likes an article it shows in on his/her timeline (Recent Activity Section) and from Your question I understand that you have a blogging system if You are running and working on WordPress use the [Facebook Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/facebook/) tell me if you need further information